# Office Web Viewer does not work properly in cordova app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building a cordova app with ionic and angular js. I need to integrate the online office viewer provided by Microsoft to view word, excel documents within the app it selt. The api requires you to load the content inside an `iframe`. When I tried to do this, it gets navigated to a in app browser. I tried implementing tha same using `ng-include` without any success. Any idea on how to implement this?

I'm using angular 1, Ionic 1, cordova 5.2.

The API I'm referring to view is [Office Web Viewer](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser/?eu=true).

Here is the sample code that I tried.

*Angular code*

```
app.config(['$sceDelegateProvider', function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/**'
  ]);
}]);

app.directive('testContent', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E', //bind to element tag name
    replace: true, //replace the entire markup with the template
    templateUrl: 'templates/test-content.html',
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.GetUrl = function () { return 'https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https://bonafidedevstorage.blob.core.windows.net/chamika-temp-blobs-1/Documents/ffe7c1fb-35bd-43ad-9e7e-68166697347b.docx'; }
    }]
  };
})
```

*Template*

```
<div>
    <p>{{GetUrl()}}</p>
    <ng-include src="GetUrl()" autoscroll></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show you code so we can understand better

Comment: @PareshGami Updated the question by adding the sample code I tried.

Comment: How you tried with iframe? i think that is very simple and easy to achieve your requirement

Comment: instead of ng-include i used iframe. But that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you please change your doc link to some dummy link because they have credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to resolve this issue with the help of a Colleague, They have given a separate url for these scenarios, Use "https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx".

Answer (score 0):

I just try below code that is working fine

```
<ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content ng-controller="mainCtrl" id="divSvg">
        <iframe height="600px" width="100%" src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=https://bonafidedevstorage.blob.core.windows.net/chamika-temp-blobs-1/Documents/e116d0fc-67e2-4fa4-aa26-8b0904506f72.docx"></iframe>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

Comment: Did you try this in a Cordova app? I tried your code but it's not working. The only change I did is removing [ng-controller="mainCtrl"] as I haven't declared a controller.

Comment: Yes in ionic v1

Comment: Hm... Can you send your code for the controller as I have used an directive. That's the only change I see in our code.

Comment: You just copy iframe tag and try in your code. My controller is blank nothing written in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159456/discussion-between-chamika-goonetilaka-and-paresh-gami).